# Mounting windows shares with Active Directory permissions

Tags: active-directory, unix, mount, server-message-block, cifs

I've managed to get my Ubuntu (server 10.04 beta 2) box to accept logins from users with Active Directory credentials, now I'd like those users to access their permissible windows shares on a W2003 R2 server.

The Windows share ("\srv\Users\") has subdirectories named according to the domain account users and permissions are set accordingly.  I would like to preserve these permissions, but don't know how to go about it.

- Would I mount as an AD administrator or have each user mount with there own AD credentials?
- How do determine between using mount.smbfs or mount.cifs?

Comment: Support for smbfs is deprecated.  You shouldn't build anything new based on that.

Comment: Can the two file system protocols work side by side?  There are some existing samba shares going on.

Comment: Both are using the same network protocol.  You should be able to use mount.cifs to access any Samba, or Windows shares.  I believe mount.cifs has all the functionality of mount.smbfs and more.  Mount.cifs has better support for unicode filenames, and large (4gb+) files.  As far as I know there is no reason to use mount.smbfs for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to setu [pam_mount](http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/).  It allows you to mount shares when a user logs into the system.  With pam_mount the folder will be mounted with the users credentials.  They credentials do not need to be saved anywhere, they will automatically be passed through by pam from what they used to login.

Comment: I'm holding out on checking the answer, only because I've not quite got it working yet.

Comment: From another question; on the same Ubuntu system `sudo apt-get install libpam-mount`