# Configuring PAM with pam_mount; getting a dlopen() with an HX_Init error

Tags: ubuntu, pam

I'm trying to get automounting upon login working on Ubuntu 10.03 Beta 2.  I didn't find a package for pam_mount, so I ended downloading it and building it.  This required:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config libxml2-dev libssl-dev libpam-dev
```

Additionally, the libHX-dev is required but as of yesterday (23/4/2010) the package version provided (3.2) wasn't up to snuff (3.4) so I downloaded, compiled and installed that too.

```
cd ./pam_mount-1.36/ && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

When I tried it (pam_mount) I got this in my auth log:

```
Apr 23 12:18:02 ubuntu sshd[1195]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/security/pam_mount.so): /lib/security/pam_mount.so: undefined symbol: HX_init
Apr 23 12:18:02 ubuntu sshd[1195]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/security/pam_mount.so
Apr 23 12:18:06 ubuntu sshd[1195]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.20.182  user=jrisk
Apr 23 12:18:06 ubuntu sshd[1195]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): getting password (0x00000388)
Apr 23 12:18:06 ubuntu sshd[1195]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): pam_get_item returned a password
Apr 23 12:18:06 ubuntu sshd[1195]: pam_winbind(sshd:auth): user 'jrisk' granted access
Apr 23 12:18:06 ubuntu sshd[1195]: Accepted password for jrisk from 192.168.20.182 port 4369 ssh2
Apr 23 12:18:06 ubuntu sshd[1195]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user jrisk by (uid=0)
```

**What do I need to do get HX_Init into the system?**

This is related to an answer I previously got [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/134976/mounting-windows-shares-with-active-directory-permissions/134981#134981).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, it is worth noting in addition to my previous answer that pam_mount is included in the Ubuntu repository as [`libpam-mount`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libpam-mount).

Answer (score 0):

The PAM module appears to be incorrectly built.
Are you sure all appropriate dependencies are installed?