# How to map to Windows Server shares in Linux (Ubuntu) easily?

Tags: linux, windows, network-share

I know how to get connected to a Windows share easy enough, and I've read how to change the fstab file to get it to mount at boot.

The real question here is...can I create a few shortcuts on a common user desktop so that regardless of who logs into Ubuntu machine they can open that shortcut and it will open the Windows share?

I would also need to allow AD credentials during login, so a link to that will help as well, but I'm sure I can search google for that part.

Comment: which desktop environment are you using? Gnome/KDE/etc? i don't know how to pass AD credentials, but you can search for system wide desktop icon for your desktop environment...

Comment: pammount maybe?  http://serverfault.com/questions/134976/mounting-windows-shares-with-active-directory-permissions/134981#134981

Comment: I figured out the AD stuff using Likewise-Open.  It still won't pass AD credentials but does allow for login at the login screen.

I'll need to look for a system wide desktop icon.  This is Gnome.

Comment: Does each Ubuntu user need to map to different shared drives?  Do they need to each login as their respective Active Directory user or is a shared AD user ok?

Comment: you can integrate Likewise-Open with Samba.  Check the integration guides on http://www.likewise.com/resources/documentation_library/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the AD logins, go with Likewise Open.  Take your time looking through the config files in /etc/likewise, as well as the documentation on the website.  Very useful in terms of managing users.  Example, I didn't know I could restrict logins to members of a local group.

As far as mounting servers, there are several ways.  Since you're using Gnome, I'll leave out [smb4k](http://smb4k.berlios.de/), since it's largely KDE based.  The latest versions of Gnome have included the ability to mount network shares via GUI.  I believe it uses FUSE to allow the user to do this without root privileges.  ONce it's connected, it actually mounts the share on a directory inside the users ~/.gvfs directory.  You can create Bookmarks or shortcuts on the desktop, then add these to the system's default /etc/skel, or use something like [Sabayon](http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon) to create the profiles you want.

Only downside to using FUSE is it's a bit slow.  If you want more speed, consider using [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs), though this is a command line tool and is less user friendly.  You'll have to cook up something via shell or python script and wrap a GUI around it to make it more user friendly.  Actually, smb4k above uses mount.cifs.  You'll also need to [set the sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) on the mount.cifs and umount.cifs commands to make them user executable.  The upside to mount.cifs is that it's fast and assuming everything else is optimal, you'll get the max throughput you can expect from cifs.

Comment: I agree - modify the default Bookmarks to include the shares you want to have. Generally, there is a default location, where the data is grabbed for a new user, and then you would need to update the profile of the existing users. You may be able to use scripting fu to get even fancier - for example, user specific bookmarks based on username. FUSE should handle the authentication - the user will get a pop-up in which to enter username/password.